# Integrate AWS XRay HttpClientBuilder with Spring Webclient

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient, aws-xray

I am using Spring Webclient for my microservices for external calls. I am trying to Integrate AWS XRay in our microservices. But to get the traces of Outgoing HTTP calls in xray, I have to use XRay HttpClientBuilder. Is there any way i can integrate XRAY HttpClientBuilder with webclient?

Comment: and what have you tried, where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

XRay java SDK currently only supports downstream HTTP Requests with Apache clients. Alternatively, you can checkout the AWS Distro for OpenTelemetry Java agent ([docs](https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/java-sdk)), which is a ready-to-use OpenTelemetry auto-instrumentation agent that's compatible with the X-Ray backend and [supports Spring WebClient](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/b78a38f85987736b46faef77b07e2e1e7f9c2cc4/instrumentation/spring/spring-webflux-5.0/library/README.md).